# Would a human survive eating only living ants?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, human-anatomy

After reading an admittedly foolish question about 1 googol ants vs. 1000 humans, I had a question. Could a human survive solely on eating ants (common ants, not the stinging kind, or leafcutters etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1469-7998.1984.tb02339.x/abstract) study in 1984 suggests it's a bad idea and other sites have said eating ants is for weight loss.

The abstract says that it goes into detail about the problems associated with eating ants as well as their low nutritional value.

So I believe the answer is no. You could not survive long term on a diet of only ants.